# Debug the code even in case of error PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I'm using the PyDev module for Eclipse debugger and I'm not able to debug my code to find out what's the reason of compilation failure! How to debug a code even if there is an error? for example this kind of error

```
a = 41
b = 'str'
print a + b
```

Edit: The question is not about the code

Comment: What do you expect `41 + 'str'` to give you? Python is dynamically typed, but also *strongly* typed - it won't implicitly coerce `41` to a string to concatenate.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you didn't understand the question, I just typed that code for example! PyDev should start to debug my code line by line even in case of error like THAT

Comment: Does PyDev not give you any error message as to *why* it won't run? Surely it tells you?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes but i want to see what does variable hold in it before giving the error... I have placed a braekpoint before the line of error but it doesn't even start to debug the code until that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you in interactive console try

preferences->pydev->interactive console and flag "connect console to a debug session"

Answer (score 0):

you can not conncat int and str:

see this doc [pydev debugger](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debugger.html)

Comment: @Streak if three separate people misunderstand the question, perhaps it is the question at fault!